# CakePHP: Why does file owner and group keep changing to root?

Tags: linux, cakephp, ubuntu, cakephp-2.0, ubuntu-12.04

I am running an install of CakePHP on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The way certain files are accessed I need permissions set a certain way within my install of Ubuntu. Nothing out of the ordinary.

The problem is that the ownership and group of certain files keeps reverting back to `root` after I manually change them to `www-data` for the owner and group.

For example, I have the following file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 155 May 10 09:26 myapp_cake_model_default_cake_apps_1_list
```

after a while, it will change to

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 155 May 10 10:13 myapp_cake_model_default_cake_apps_1_list
```

This is happening in a couple of locations. `/var/app/tmp/cache` and `/var/app/tmp/cache/models/`.

I'm not sure if this is happening because of a cron or Ubuntu doesn't like the permissions or because I'm a moron and idiot. But It's driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: check the inode of the file before/after the perms change. if the inode changes, then something is creating a NEW file, deleting the old one, then renaming the new file. it'd most likely be a cron job of some sort, because apache itself could NOT create a file owned by root after it's finished its startup routine and dropped privs.

Comment: @bikemike7801, can you verify which user Apache is running as? Does this happen to all files in these locations? If not, I'd agree with MarkB, sounds like a CRON job.

Comment: If this is because of cronjob, how can a make the cronjob not be created as "root"?

Comment: You can modify cron job users by editing the crontab file found in `/etc/crontab` ([source](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=4107))

Comment: @SamDelaney I'm not seeing an area to edit the actual users in that File.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the temp files depends on the user running the script. If there are files being created with "root" as owner most likely cause is a cronjob (or manually) running a cakephp shell with sudo permissions.